# passportjs with twitter, what am i doing wrong here to use the search api by twitter.?

Tags: api, search, twitter, oauth, passport.js

```js
exports.findt = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.user.tokens.find(token => token.kind === 'twitter');
  const T = new Twit({
    consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_SECRET,
    access_token: token.accessToken,
    access_token_secret: token.tokenSecret
  });
  T.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Twitter%20API&page=1&count=3', (err, reply) => {

    if (err) { console.log(err) }
    res.status(res).json(reply);
  });
};
```

this is part of my controller, duplicated from hackathon-starter node app.